# How to align image and download button in css?

Tags: html, css

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4478bs0L/

I need to place download button underneath of image at left side.

For that, here is my html:

```
<div><img src="9780143332497.jpg" alt="">
<a href="9780143332497.jpg" class="myButton" download="ss" title="Download">
    <img src="/path/to/image" alt="Download">
</a></div>
```

If i add caption class to the button and set text-align:center; it didn't working.

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: just set `img` to `display:block` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4478bs0L/1/)

Comment: thanks @VitorinoFernandes.. simple.. but i didn't know...

Comment: by default the `img` and `a` is `inline` which is aligning them one after another so when you change the property to `block` it will not allow the other element to align next to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Option1**: Add a `<br/>` between both images.[Apparently, your button is also an image]. Sometimes the simplest answer is the easiest.

  ```
  <img src="image1" alt=""> 
  <br/>
  <a href="image2" class="myButton" download="ss" title="Download">
    <img src="/path/to/image" alt="Download">
  </a>
  ```
- **Option 2**: enclose your button inside a `<div>` [ block element]

  ```
  <div>
   <a href="http://s30.postimg.org/b7rdjjkwh/9780143332497.jpg" class="myButton" download="ss" title="Download">
     <img src="/path/to/image" style="display:block"alt="Download"/>
   </a>
  </div>
  ```
- **Option 3**: add *inline* css property `display:block` to the anchor tag containing your button[inline css would override the `myButton` class property which is making it appear on the same line]

  ```
  <a href="http://s30.postimg.org/b7rdjjkwh/9780143332497.jpg" class="myButton" style="display:block;width:60px"  download="ss" title="Download">
   <img src="/path/to/image" alt="Download">
  </a>
  ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

just use a `<br>` after the image and before the button

```
<div><img src="9780143332497.jpg" alt="">
<br>
<a href="9780143332497.jpg" class="myButton" download="ss" title="Download">    
<img src="/path/to/image" alt="Download">
</a></div>
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xx96fgrh/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I did it .... implement this code...

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="london-olympic">
<h1>Playng To Win</h1>
<span class="span">Author: <a href="#">Saina Nehwal.</a></span>
<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<div class="addthis_jumbo_share"></div>
<div><img src="http://s30.postimg.org/b7rdjjkwh/9780143332497.jpg" alt="">
<a style="position:absolute; margin-left: -140px; top: 450px;" href="http://s30.postimg.org/b7rdjjkwh/9780143332497.jpg" class="myButton" download="ss" title="Download">
    <img src="/path/to/image" alt="Download">
</a>
</div>
<Br><br>
<p>. . . being a player from India defines who I am. When I play, it's for my parents, my coach, and my country.'</p>

<p>Meet Saina Nehwal-India's star badminton player and World Number 4, Padma Shri and Khel Ratna awardee, the girl who brought laurels to India by winning an Olympic medal at the age of twenty-two.  In this fascinating memoir, she talks about her childhood and growing-up years; her relationship with the most important people in her life; the ups and downs of her celebrated career, from district level wins to the Olympics; and the sacrifices needed to succeed in any sport. She also reveals little-known facts and offers a peek into her many avatars-daughter, sister, student, and the regular girl behind the badminton prodigy.</p>

<p>Find out what a typical day in Saina's life is like-rigorous training, a strict diet, and no parties or sleepovers. But it's not all work and no play; Saina loves to shop, eat ice cream (post wins only), and play games on her iPad!</p>

<p>With candid photographs and badminton tips from the pro herself, this book showcases the making of a badminton champ-in her own words.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code**

```
 <div>
     <img src="9780143332497.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div>
     <a href="9780143332497.jpg" class="myButton" download="ss" title="Download">
    <img src="/path/to/image" alt="Download">
     </a>
</div>
```